# Validation data using api

Tags: php, ajax, api

I need to validate some form data both in client-side and server-side (php). I can use some API web service to check the data form. The problem is: I can validate the data, in client side, using an Ajax call and my API web service. How can I use the API web service from server-side?

Comment: Validate just inside your **php code** !! That's it.

Comment: So I can't call API from php code? @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: You can call. If you use any External API to validate your data, then call it from php code and that's it the server side validation :)

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to call External API from php code, can you explain me or link me some website? @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: Sure.. Writing you answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to invoke external call

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

And there you can send the parameter from the url itself,

Here the example to send parameter to your api

Construct an array and place your values to be validated

```
$getdata = http_build_query(
array(
 'name' => 'Francesco',
 'phone' => '2434343',
 'age'=>'23',
 'city'=>'MA',
 'state'=>'US'
 )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $getdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
```

Then send it to your api's directly

```
file_get_contents('http://example.com/send.php?'.$getdata, false, $context);
```

Comment: Can you explain me what is context parameter?

Comment: Ah, that's what i am still waiting you to ask. I build the headers as an array :)

Comment: What is postdata in the header content?

Comment: Sorry it was a type, i used to post the answer from my tablet device. So it happend , Updated the answe :)